# Undefined property inside method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a simple splash screen using OOP in javascript. I want to create a code which will allow the user's to cycle through the game menu but i stumbled upon an error. I am trying to access `this.state, this.selection` inside the `control()` method but they both return undefined even though they both are declared in the `constructor()` function of the class.
Here's some of my code

```js
class Game {
  constructor() {
    this.menu = ['Start', 'Load', 'Exit'];
    this.selection = 1;
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('game');
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.state = 'menu';
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.control, false);

    this.splash();
  }

  control(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    console.log(this.state, this.selection);
    if (this.state == 'menu') {
      console.log('true');
      splash(e.keyCode);
    } else {
      return e.keyCode;
    }
  }

  splash(key) {
    console.log('successfully initialized');
    if (key == 38) {
      this.selection--;
      console.log(this.menu[this.selection]);
    } else if (key == 40) {
      this.selection++;
      console.log(this.menu[this.selection]);
    }
  }
}


var game = new Game;
```

When i use `console.log(this.state, this.selection);` it returns undefined for both properites, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: your `this` is out of scope, probably inside `control()` it is refering to window, and you want it to refer to `Game`. Try to bind when setting the listener: `....addEventListener('keydown', this.control.bind(this), false)`

Comment: You are loggin it inside the control method, so `this` points to control.

Comment: @CalvinNunes that apparently worked, can you post it as an answer so i can choose yours as the correct one?

Comment: somebody already did it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `this` inside the event handler no longer refers to your game instance. You can solve this by using `bind(this)`.

Another problem is you were missing `this` from the call to `splash`. I fixed that also in the example below.

```js
class Game{
  constructor(){
    this.menu = ['Start', 'Load', 'Exit'];
    this.selection = 1;
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('game');
    //this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.state = 'menu';
    window.addEventListener('keydown',this.control.bind(this),false);

    this.splash();
  }

  control(e){
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    console.log(this.state, this.selection);
    if(this.state == 'menu'){
      console.log('true');
      this.splash(e.keyCode);
    }else{
      return e.keyCode;
    }
  }

  splash(key){
    console.log('successfully initialized');
    if(key == 38){
      this.selection--;
      console.log(this.menu[this.selection]);
    }else if(key == 40){
      this.selection++;
      console.log(this.menu[this.selection]);
    }
  }  
}

var game = new Game();
```

```html
<div id="game"></div>
```